# Finding the first "x-th consecutive day"

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

Given the following data,

```
SELECT setseed(0.5);

WITH stuff AS (
    SELECT d::date, floor(random() * 5) AS v
    FROM generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-01-15'::date, '1 day'::interval) t(d)
)
SELECT d, v
FROM stuff
WHERE extract(isodow from d) BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

More concretely,

```
     d      | v
------------+---
 2021-01-01 | 1  -- 1st consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-04 | 1  -- 2nd consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-05 | 0  -- 0th consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-06 | 0  -- 0th consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-07 | 0  -- 0th consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-08 | 1  -- 1st consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-11 | 0  -- 0th consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-12 | 4  -- 1st consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-13 | 3  -- 2nd consecutive day with a positive `v`
 2021-01-14 | 1  -- 3rd consecutive day with a positive `v` (this!)
 2021-01-15 | 3  -- 4th consecutive day with a positive `v`
(11 rows)
```

I want to find the first "3rd consecutive day with a positive `v`". In the example above, `2021-01-12` through `2021-01-14` all meet the criteria, so the expected answer is `2021-01-14`. A `NULL` should be returned in case no such day exists.

Currently, I'm using `pandas` to fetch the data into Python and calculate the answer with a counter, but I'd like to switch to PostgreSQL for performance reasons. An obvious solution is to use a recursive CTE, but I want to avoid that in favor of some custom aggregate function or PL/pgSQL procedure since the solution will become part of a larger query, so I must try to keep it simple to avoid an explosion in query complexity. I mean, it would be ridiculous to have a recursive CTE inside another recursive CTE inside a `LATERAL` ...

Answer (score 1):

I have used window functions, however I am not sure of the performance of such solution:

```sql
SELECT setseed(0.5);

WITH stuff AS (
    SELECT d::date, floor(random() * 5) AS v
    FROM generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-01-15'::date, '1 day'::interval) t(d)
), tmp as (
    SELECT d, v, 
    LAG(v) OVER (ORDER BY d) AS v2, 
    LAG(v, 2) OVER (ORDER BY d) AS v3
    FROM stuff
    WHERE extract(isodow from d) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
)
SELECT d
FROM tmp
WHERE v > 0 and v2 > 0 AND v3 > 0
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Your method is basically fine, but without an `order by` in the outer query, any row meeting the conditions might be returned, rather than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can write a custom aggregation without knowing PL/pgSQL, so here is what I did. In general, it should be `retval_consecutive[2] = x - 1` for the first "x-th consecutive day".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_xth_consecutive_label_transfn(retval_consecutive int[2], label_cond int[2])
    RETURNS int[2]
    LANGUAGE sql
    IMMUTABLE AS
$$
SELECT CASE
           WHEN retval_consecutive[1] IS NOT NULL THEN
               retval_consecutive -- already found
           WHEN label_cond[2] = 1 THEN
               ARRAY [CASE WHEN retval_consecutive[2] = 2 THEN label_cond[1] END, retval_consecutive[2] + 1]
           ELSE
               ARRAY [NULL, 0]
           END
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_xth_consecutive_label_final(ans_consecutive int[2])
    RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE sql
    IMMUTABLE AS
$$
SELECT ans_consecutive[1];
$$;


DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS first_xth_consecutive_label(int[2]);
CREATE AGGREGATE first_xth_consecutive_label(int[2]) (
    sfunc = first_xth_consecutive_label_transfn,
    stype = int[2],
    finalfunc = first_xth_consecutive_label_final,
    initcond = '{NULL, 0}'
    );
```

Usage:

```
SELECT setseed(0.5);

WITH stuff AS (
    SELECT d::date, floor(random() * 5) AS v
    FROM generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-01-15'::date, '1 day'::interval) t(d)
)
SELECT to_timestamp(first_xth_consecutive_label(ARRAY [extract(epoch FROM d)::int, CASE WHEN v > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END]))::date
FROM stuff
WHERE extract(isodow from d) BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```